# Ext.Date.format() in Sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I want to get date format like **2017-04-20 00:00:00**

currently my code is

```
this.ToDatePicker = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'name',
        labelAlign: 'top',
        fieldLabel: 'Date Time',
        value: Ext.Date.format(new Date(), "d-m-Y h:iA"),
        listeners: {
            scope: this,
            afterrender: function (c) {
                c.getEl().on('click', function (e) {
                    console.log(e.target)
                    NewCssCal_DisableAfterToday(Ext.get(e.target).dom.id, 'ddmmyyyy', 'dropdown', true, 12)
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

need to update `Ext.Date.format(new Date(), "d-m-Y h:iA")`
to get that date format as I needed. Can you have any idea to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`Ext.Date`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Date.html), you can use:

```
Ext.Date.format(new Date(), "Y-m-d h:i:s")
```

Comment: Here in this case I will complete date without timezone, What will the code for print complete date with time zone eg `"09-Oct-2020 02:54:58" IST`. In doc aslo it is not cear/